# For Each is not working, just goes to the first element and then exits, How can i fix this?

Tags: genexus

I have Two For Each that access to different tables to access the data on them But on the second for each only enter once and exits without looping, I am trying to print data from a procedure on a txt file

I have already checked the tables and they have more than one value, Rebuild the knowledge base, I have checked that it only goes once.
here is the code:

```
For Each Table1 
    Where Attribute1= &Attribute1
        &Flag = 0
    For Each Table2
        WHERE Attribute2= &Attribute2
        If &Flag=0
            Print Tittle
            &Flag =1
        EndIf
        Print Transacctions
    EndFor
    Print Footer
EndFor
```

Comment: @r210: Check the navigation. As you have an outer for each and an inner for each, if the tables involved are related GeneXus will add filters to the inner for each (records that match the attributes of the outer for each). If that's the case you can move the inner for each onto a subroutine and call it (`do`) inside the outer for each.

Comment: @sebagomez: yes is a typo

Comment: @gusbro: mind making an example, am relatively new on genexus and I can't Quite understand what you´re trying to say (english is not my first language )

Comment: @r210: The actual solution will depend on what you are actually trying to do and the data model. Can you update your question and provide the structure of Table1 and Table2 (so we can see the relation).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check specification navigation to see if gx is navigatig between the two tables you want.
Another tip i'd tell you is to put sniffers to see what is happening during execution.
And finally, chech taht in your DB, there are more than one record taht match the condition WHERE Attribute2= &Attribute2 and  Attribute1= &Attribute1.
Luck